# Can we prove Prime number theorem by prime factorization?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

> Number of prime before a sufficiently large $N$ equals to $\frac{N}{\log(N)}$.
>
> Is there a way to prove it by prime factorizations?

Suppose $N$, and all the primes $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_j\}$, thus all the number below $N$ was of the form $r=p_1^{\alpha_1}  p_2 ^{\alpha_1} ...p_j^{\alpha_j}$.

Computationally speaking, we know that if we took $\log_{10}(r)$ we could get the "digits" of the number $r$ under $N$. Therefore, suppose $N=10^{10}$, we could easily compute all the unique "permutation/tuple" of those prime number whose bijective $r_l$ had value under $N$. Say we have $q$ of those permutations whose bijective values smaller or equal to $N$. Then we know for sure that $N=q+1$(or if we justify 1 as the 0 tuple), otherwise we know there was some prime number missing from the set.

Since this is a computational result, it must be true for all $N$ of order $10^k$.(If we let $log_{10}(r_i)$ compute more digits, it would be true for all $N$.)
Thus such relation must hold for all $N$. (Think if we had a table of holes with primes as index, and we use those permutation/tuple to fill out the holes(the missing numbers), until we couldn't. Then we must have obtained a new prime.)

Notice the interesting part about this question:

First: the program itself is highly efficient: if we save every integer it generated as tuple $X(r)=r$ and make the iteration with respect $N$ itself, then we generate the nature number exactly once. There is no "deviation" towards the number, or any other logical statement except comparing the size of the number, and count the order of the set we had already generated.

Second: Although it calculated out all the non-primes. Notice the existence and generating of the prime was independent of calculation. We simply count the size of the generated sets below $N$. If it's $N-1$, then $N$ was a prime. Thus if we would effectively obtain the prime generating function if we can prove it through prime factorization.

Comment: This is the Prime Number Theorem. If you can prove it by this sort of elementary consideration, fame beckons!

Comment: With elementary arguments, you can't prove the PNT, but you can find some heuristics justifying why we want $\sum_{p \le x} 1 \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$ (the heuristic is to assume a random model for the prime numbers where $X_n = 1_{n \text{ is prime }}$ is a sequence of *independent* random variables)

Comment: I wouldn't say "equals to..." First, the right hand side isn't an integer.

Comment: @reuns not "you can't" just has not been done

Comment: If I were to look for a simple proof, I'd try to use that the harmonic mean of $1,2,\dots,n$ $\sim\frac{n}{\log n}$.

Comment: I really meant you can't make the proof of the PNT simpler without studying first the complicated proofs. Take a look at the [Mertens theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems). @ThomasAndrews $\text{Li}(x) \sim \sum_{2 \le n \le x} \frac{1}{\log n}$ essentially comes from $\zeta(s) \sim \frac{1}{s-1}$ so that $\sum_p p^{-s} \sim\log \zeta(s) \sim -\int \zeta(s) ds = \sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{n^{-s}}{\log n}$

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about a technique that doesn't look at all those things. @reuns Basically, how can we get something asymptotic to $\frac{n}{\log n}$ while talking about simple operations.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't think there is anything simpler than starting from $e^{ \log \zeta(s)} = \zeta(s)$  where $\log \zeta(s)$ is very complicated ( generating series of the primes) while the RHS is a very simple series. It gives **directly** $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log x}$ in some weak sense (Mertens theorems)

Comment: The closest theorem I thought related to was pigeonhole principle. We had infinite pigeon each fits exactly 1 holes, thus there must be infinite holes. However, if we had finite $N$ pigeons, then we must have $N$ holes. If we arrange those holes into a table of $k$ columns, and there was only $N-1$ holes in those $k$ columns, then we must have a $k+1$ columns. This was the simplest description of the question. So the proof must exists, and can we write it out? and generalize it to the generating function?

Comment: In Hardy and Wright there is an elementary proof of $\pi(n)=O(\frac{n}{\log n})$ if I'm not mistaken it's proved in $22.3$ or $22.4$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Couldn't get the book, but the title was Bertrad's postulate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate , I was thinking could we prove it through prime factorization? Because, at my point of view, by using prime factorization, the existence of prime number and its number below certain integer $N$ became rather an algebraic property, so the existence and generating was not because we could calculate it. So we should get an exact answer for each large $N$. It's somewhat different but similar to Euclid's Proof of the Infinitude of Primes.

Comment: So can we find any permutation or arrangement through analysis its ring structure and write it out by prime factorization? Because if we can, the answer should be exact for each $N$. For example, some extra thinking for Bertrad's postulate: 
$1,2,3,4,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53...1=1*1+0, 2=1*1+1, 3=1*2+1, 5=2*3-1, 7=2*3+1, 11=2*5+1, 13=3*5-2, 17=3*5+2, 19=3*7-2,23=3*7+2,29=2*11+7,31=2*17-3,37=2*17-3,37=5*7+2/2*19-1,41=3*13+2,47=2*23+1,53=17*3+2$